# Parallelizing function which takes a class object instance as input argument with Joblib

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pickle, joblib

I have an object class with the init function defined as follows

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2, arg3=True, ...):
        ...
```

I want to parallelize a function that takes an instance of my Foo class as an input. But it throws the following error

```
foo = F(arg1, arg2, arg3)
Parallel(n_jobs=-1)(delayed(fun)(x, y, foo) for x, y in [args])

__init__() missing 1 required positional argument ...
```

From what I understand when the foo object is pickled by Joblib, it creates a copy of my foo class instance, but for some reason the copy isn't properly initialized with all the right arguments.

Comment: *every parameter always takes a class instance as an argument*

Comment: In any case, you really must provide a [mcve], including a full error message with the stack trace

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thanks for the comment, working on the minimal reproducible example got me the solution. I should have done that before posting the question.

Comment: Thats why it's required for debugging questions :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that my class was inheriting another class that had a method that makes a copy of itself, and when it does that, it did not pass my inherited class's additional parameters.